# How to map state to props on the initial file (App.js or Index.js)?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

This is probably something very basic. There is a spinner on my App where the routes and providers are declared. This must be reading the redux store, in particular spinner.visible and map to state so I can hide/show the `<Spinner>` element.

But as I said...this is the entry file of the app. I know how to map it to props using connect, but looks like I can't use connect/mapStateToProps on my entry file.

This works very good, but I don't think that using a subscribe is the best way. I'd like to make the spinner be capable to read the store directly in an elegant way. Any suggestions ?

```
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {View} from 'react-native'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducers from './reducers'
import Routes from './config/routes'
import {getReady} from './services/registration'
import {setAppInitialLoad, setAppSpinner} from './actions/AppActions'

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        initialized: false,
        spinner: {
            visible: false,
            text: ''
        }
    }
    store.subscribe(() => {
            //ToDo: I really hope to find an elegant solition for this.
            //Since it' the top level JS file of the app, I can't use
            //connect/mapStateToProps to map the props :(
            const spinner = store.getState().AppReducer.spinner
            if(spinner.visible != this.state.spinner.visible) {
                this.setState({
                    spinner: {
                        visible: spinner.visible,
                        text: spinner.text
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    )
}
componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(setAppSpinner({ visible: true, text: 'Loading...'}))
    getReady().then(response => {
        store.dispatch(setAppInitialLoad(response.data.data))
        store.dispatch(setAppSpinner({ visible: false, text: ''}))
        this.setState({initialized: true})
    })
}

render() {
    if (this.state.initialized) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Routes/>
                </Provider>
                <Spinner visible={this.state.spinner.visible} textContent={this.state.spinner.text}
                         textStyle={{color: '#000'}}/>
            </View>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', flex: 1}}/>
        )
    }
}
}
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use store variable 
(In your code, it here: `const store = createStore(reducers, {}, ...)`

store variable has some method, you can read at here (https://redux.js.org/basics/store)